# AIR Android - How to Make a Peer-To-Peer Connection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, p2p

I have developed an Android app using Flash / AIR and was wondering how I could set up a peer-to-peer connection (p2p) such that :

- Users of the app can select certain choices in the app and search for peers.
- If they are in proximity to other users with mutual selections then their phones vibrate.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Here we help each other with code issues. Please try something first (ie: find an online tutorial/article) and then ask here if your practice app is not working. You must also show smallest testable code that re-creates your connection problem so we can advise.

Comment: In case you're stuck for tutorial search keywords : [**AS3 Peer to Peer**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as3%22+%22android%22+peer-to-peer+connection) and [**AS3 phone vibrate**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as3%22+%22android%22+phone+vibrate). Ask here about one issue at a time. I think your priority is getting a p2p connection first.

Comment: My problem is once I have the connection, how will I be able to make the choices selected by the users search if their selections match. I have found on the web codes such as: switch(condition)
{
  case condition 1:
  trace("Condition 1 was met");
  break;
  case condition 2:
  trace("Condition 2 was met");
  break;
  case condition 3:
  trace("Condition 3 was met");
  break;
  default:
  trace("None of the above were met");
} but this searches for data locally (within one phone). I want my app to search for data in another phone that has the same app and viceversa.....